# Why is the onClick button telling me dispatch is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `onDeleteClick` function which is giving me an error when I try to click it and response is dispatched is not a function and the error is indicated to be coming from this code

I changed the single quote to back-ticks and still got the same result

```
class Contact extends Component {
  state = {
    showContactInfo: false
  };

  onDeleteClick = (id, dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: "DELETE_CONTACT", payload: id });
  };

  render() {
    const { name, id, email, phone } = this.props.contact;
    const { showContactInfo } = this.state;

    return (
      <Consumer>
        {value => {
          const { dispatch } = value;
          return (
            <div className="card card-body mb-3">
              <h4>
                {name}
                <i
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.setState({
                      showContactInfo: !this.state.showContactInfo
                    })
                  }
                  className="fas fa-sort-down"
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "indigo" }}
                />
                <i
                  className="fas fa-times"
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", float: "right", color: "blue" }}
                  onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, id, dispatch)}
                />
              </h4>
              {showContactInfo ? (
                <ul className="list-group">
                  <li className="list-group-item">Email: {email}</li>
                  <li className="list-group-item">Phone: {phone}</li>
                </ul>
              ) : null}
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Consumer>
    );
  }
}

Contact.propTypes = {
  contact: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Contact;
```

I want the `onDelete` function to be able to delete from the list.

Comment: well, do you have a function `dispatch` inside `value` object?

Comment: I think we have to know a bit more about Consumer component :)

Comment: There is no consumer component and the dispatch is destructured from the value itself, chrome is telling me the issue is at onDeleteClick function

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to bind `onDeleteClick` when using arrow function in class instance.

Moreover, you call the `onDeleteClick` instead of assigning it as a callback.

```
// On given params, return a function
onDeleteClick = (id, dispatch) => () => {
  dispatch({ type: "DELETE_CONTACT", payload: id });
};
```

```
class Contact extends Component {
  ...
//                               v Assign as a callback
  onDeleteClick = (id, dispatch) => () => {
    dispatch({ type: "DELETE_CONTACT", payload: id });
  };

  render() {
    const { id , ... } = this.props.contact;
    return (
      <Consumer>
        {value => {
          const { dispatch } = value;
          return (
            <div>
              <h4>
                  ...
                <i
//                                           v No bind needed
                  onClick={this.onDeleteClick(id, dispatch)}
                />
              </h4>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue, the issue has pointed out in the browser and console is here   dispatch({ type: "DELETE_CONTACT", payload: id });

Comment: So you should show all your code because there is no `dispatch` in `value`